# How can I instruct excel to execute my .xla file automatically on startup?

Tags: excel

I have a .xla located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel-udf-concat.xla that I need to execute upon start up

At the moment I must load excel first and then manually execute that file, sometimes I forget to do this and my formula does not get executed!

Is there a way to instruct excel to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to the Excel addins list: File-->Options-->Addins-->XL Addins-->Browse.

That will make your addin open automatically. If you want it to run a sub when it opens just add the appropriate code to its Workbook_Open event